# in Javascript, In IE8, Object's method which is attached in event hold 'window object' instead Object itself at 'this'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, methods, internet-explorer-8

```
var o = {
   f : function() {
      this.p();
   }
   p : function() {
      alert("run!");
   }
}

element.addEventListener("click", o.f);
//addEventListener is overrode for older IE version.
```

in this code, `element` has click event which handled object `o`'s method `o.f()`.
if I run that method directly like this

```
o.f();
```

it works fine. it would display alert message box contain the text "run!".

but in IE8, when the click event is fired, it display an error. "`this` has no method p."(`undefined`)

Because in other browser and newest IE version, `this` contains object `o` itself. but older IE contains `Window Object`.

I would want to fix this. to make `this` pointing object itself. not `window`.

Is it possible?

Comment: Unless `o` changes or you otherwise *need* `this`, you could replace `this.p();` with `o.p();`

Answer (score 3):

For IE8 (or actually any browser), you will need to change it from this:

```
element.addEventListener("click", o.f);
```

to this:

```
element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   return o.f(e);
});
```

When you pass `o.f`, you are only passing a reference to the `f` function.  The reference to the object `o` is lost.  So, it ends up just calling `f` without setting `this` as desired.  In newer browsers you could do this:

```
element.addEventListener("click", o.f.bind(o));
```

But, `.bind()` is not available in IE8 so my first recommendation is more cross browser.  FYI, this all assumes you're making `.addEventListener` work in IE8 (per your comments).

Comment: but i'm using removeEventListener too. is there another way?

Comment: @Selshas - yes, you can create an actual named function that calls `o.f()` and then use that with both `.addEventListener()` and `.removeEventListener()`.

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara Object `o` is prototype. so in actual code, `o` must deal with each derivatives.

Comment: overrode `.addEventListener` just rename of `.attachEvent`.